# Rails registration on landing page to complete registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I have a home-landing-page that is my root url. I want users to begin the sign up process here where they input only their email, click signup, and continue the registration on a separate page.

This is the part of the form I want on the home-root-landing-page

```
<div>
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %>
</div>
```

This is what the full (separate) signup page looks like. I would like the email address the users entered on the home-root-landing-page to auto populate on this page (after they hit signup and are redirected to this page.)

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I'm using devise and I'm having trouble on how I would simply approach this. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

In your view that you are rendering in homepage, set the `form` action to the signup page `/user/signup`.

In the signup controller, initialize the `@user` with the params that you've received from the homepage.

```
#UsersController
def signup
  @user = User.new(params[:user]
end
```

The above action will render `signup` view. Now use @user in the `form_for`. Like:

```
form_for(@user)
```

This will auto populate the first name and email.

However, it is apparent that you're using Devise. I'm not sure it will work for its default controllers as it is initilizing the resource from empty hash (i see the following code in source)

```
  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    respond_with resource
  end
```

So, you may have to [override the registration controller](https://gist.github.com/2343176).

Comment: I'm not understanding, I think maybe I have worded it in a bad way please see my revision/edit.

Comment: I'm "closing" this question as it's no the best design solution to achieve what I would like the user to experience.

Comment: no, your description is ok. i gave some scattered ideas and i thought you will get it right. if you need further explanation, please let me know, i will try to explain

Comment: I've posted a better design question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689188/devise-registration-form-on-any-page I plan to render the registration form on the homepage and use jQuery hide and show to create a wizard of sorts for this method of signing up. If you can offer help at the above question I would appreciate it :)