# Devise Registration form on any page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, devise, controller

I'm trying to allow users to sign up for the site on my home/landing page.
I've duplicated the devise registration form into my landing page view-

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

And I've also [added the helper methods](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app) in my `application_controller.rb` so that I properly define the resource-

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

However I'm still getting the error `undefined local variable or method` `resource'`for #<#:0x007fa816b4b750>`

What am I missing here to properly render a REGISTRATION form on my home landing page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to declare those controller methods as helper methods to access them from the views:

```
helper_method :resource, :resource_name, :devise_mapping
```

Just add that line inside your `ApplicationController` after the methods are defined.

You'll notice that the link you provided actually mentions to put this code in the application *helper*, not the controller...  You can avoid this `helper_method` declaration if you do it that way.

Comment: PinnyM, you the real MVP! Worked like a charm.